# Accessing a hyphenated attribute using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below syntax works:

```
hello = $("html").find('[id=foo-var]').html();
```

But how do we specify "foo-var" through a variable?

```
var holder = "foo-var";
hello = $("html").find('[id=' + holder + ']').html();
```

This of course, doesn't work.

Comment: The easier and better syntax to select an element with id is to use .find('#foo-var') and then replacing with variable should also work .find('#'+holder)

Comment: `var yoMama = 'foo-var'; document.querySelector('#'+yoMama).innerHTML; //pound yoMama innerHTML` *sorry, i couldn't resist*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the attribute value in quotes if it contains a restricted character:

```
var holder = "foo-var";
var hello = $("html").find('[id="' + holder + '"]').html();
```

***However*** given that `id` attributes have to be unique in the DOM you should be using an `id` selector in the first instance:

```
var holder = "foo-var";
var hello = $('#' + holder).html();
```

If you have multiple elements with the same `id` then that's a separate problem which needs to be addressed in your HTML.

Comment: It works. And thanks for the extra bit of advice.

However, it's not that the IDs aren't unique. It's that the objects don't exist during the initial page load. So I access it via a pre-existing parent node("html" in this case).

Comment: You can still use `$('#' + holder).html()` even if the element isn't in the DOM when the page loads. So long as it exists when you run the JS to select it, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the quotes `"'"`

```
var holder = "foo-var";
hello = $("html").find('[id="' + holder + '"]').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literal for better looking syntax

`` $("html").find(`[id=${holder}]`).html(); ``